# xpath find nodes without class and without id

Tags: xhtml, xpath, css-selectors

How to find nodes without id and class attributes in a xhtml document ?

Comment: Post a sample of your XML and explain what nodes you need to select. As it stands, your question is too generic for a real answer to be given.

Comment: http://pastie.org/1398730 something like that

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted elements. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From a comment of @astropanic (the OP):

> I want all li nodes that doesn't have
>   id or class attributes

**Use**:

```
//li[not(@id) and not(@class)]
```

This selects all `li` elements in the XML document such that the `li` element has no `id` and no `class` attributes.